# Jenkinsfile variable not getting set for helm

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, kubernetes-helm, jenkins-groovy

I've a Jenkinsfile within which I call upon helm install command via shell script.

I pass a config variable called host_ingress:

```
      steps {
        script {
          info "Starting Deploy";
          
          switch(kubeNamespace) {
            case "***":
              host_ingress=".foo.com"
              .
              .
              .
              .
              .
            break;
            
            .
            .
            .
            .
             sh script: """
                ./bin/helm.sh ${dryrun}\\
                    -t '${appVersion}' \\
                    -r '${helmReleaseName}' \\
                    -f ${helmChart}/${valuesFile} \\
                    --namespace '${kubeNamespace}' \\
                    --set ...... \\
                    --set host_ingress='${dml_ingress_host}' \\
                    --set grafana..... \\             
              """ , label: "Deploy with Helm"
```

And in my ingress.yaml file I have:

```
spec:
  rules:
    - host: {{ $host_ingress }}
      http:
        paths:
```

It is getting set correctly within jenkins but fails:

*Error: parse error at (*****/templates/ingress.yaml:20): undefined variable "$host_ingress"*

I've tried loads of options of what it could be and am having no luck.

Comment: We need to see your Jenkins Pipeline code to assist with this.

Comment: I've amended the original post which shows the original pipeline code.

Answer (score 0):

To set [environment variables](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#using-environment-variables) in jenkinsfile you can do like the examples bellow

```
pipeline {
   agent any
   environment {
       host_ingress = '.foo.bar.com' //can be used in whole pipeline
 ...
```

or

```
steps {
    script {
      info "Starting Deploy";
      
      switch(kubeNamespace) {
        case "***":
          environment { 
              host_ingress=".foo.com" //can be used in this stage only
          }
```

Comment: Its ok setting the varibable but fails in passing onto helm ingress.yaml